# How to customize bibliography and citation style using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

Recently I decided to switch from MS Word to LaTeX to write my papers. I'm having a little problems with the managment of my citations and bibliography, especially when is asked for use different styles for different purposes.

I was thinking in create different tex files for the different bibliography and citations style, but I don't know how to edit correctly the style.

This papers (Save as Example.bib):

```
@Article{Ho2012,
  author   = {Ho, L. and Dreyfus, J. and Boyer, J. and Lowe, T. and Bustamante, H. and Duker, P. and Meli, T. and Newcombe, G.},
  title    = {Fate of cyanobacteria and their metabolites during water treatment sludge management processes},
  journal  = {Sci Total Environ},
  year     = {2012},
  volume   = {424},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {232-238},
  issn     = {1879-1026 (Electronic)
0048-9697 (Linking)},
  note     = {Many notes},
  doi      = {10.1016/j.scitotenv.2012.02.025},
  keywords = {Many keywords},
  type     = {Journal Article},
  url      = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22444068},
}

@Article{Ho2007,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Hoefel, D. and Saint, C. P. and Newcombe, Gayle},
  title    = {Isolation and identification of a novel microcystin-degrading bacterium from a biological sand filter},
  journal  = {Water Res},
  year     = {2007},
  volume   = {41},
  number   = {20},
  pages    = {4685-4695},
  issn     = {0043-1354 (Print)
0043-1354 (Linking)},
  note     = {Many notes},
  doi      = {10.1016/j.watres.2007.06.057},
  keywords = {Many keywords},
  type     = {Journal Article},
  url      = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17640697},
}

@Article{Ho2012a,
  author   = {Ho, L. and Sawade, E. and Newcombe, G.},
  title    = {Biological treatment options for cyanobacteria metabolite removal: A review},
  journal  = {Water Res},
  year     = {2012},
  volume   = {46},
  number   = {5},
  pages    = {1536-1548},
  issn     = {1879-2448 (Electronic)
0043-1354 (Linking)},
  note     = {Many notes},
  doi      = {10.1016/j.watres.2011.11.018},
  keywords = {Many keywords},
  type     = {Journal Article},
  url      = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22133838},
}
```

Should be cited and referenced this way:

Way 1

> (Ho *et al.*, 2007; 2012a; b)
>   **References**
>
> Ho, L., Dreyfus, J., Boyer, J., Lowe, T., Bustamante, H., Duker, P.,
>   Meli, T. and Newcombe, G. (2012a). Fate of cyanobacteria and their
>   metabolites during water treatment sludge management processes. Sci
>   Total Environ, 424(1), 232-238.
>
> Ho, L., Hoefel, D., Saint, C. P. and Newcombe, G. (2007). Isolation
>   and identification of a novel microcystin-degrading bacterium from a
>   biological sand filter. Water Res, 41(20), 4685-4695.
>
> Ho, L., Sawade, E. and Newcombe, G. (2012b). Biological treatment
>   options for cyanobacteria metabolite removal: A review. Water Res,
>   46(5), 1536-1548.

In LaTeX I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,
bibstyle=authoryear,
giveninits=true,
maxcitenames=2,
uniquelist=false,
sortcites,
maxbibnames=99,
sorting=ynt,
url=false,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
\addbibresource{Example.bib}

%For italic et al. %%%
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}
%%%

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\begin{document}
\parencite{Ho2012,Ho2012a,Ho2007}
\printbibliography[sorting=nyt]
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

How can I

1. erase the notes and ISNN from the bibliography (yellow and blue marks)?
2. avoid "In:" before the journal name (green mark)?
3. put the journal name in plain text (pink mark)?
4. do volume(issue) (orange marke)?
5. the citations is sorted by year, and I tryed to print the bibliography sorted by name, but clearly the code \printbibliography[sorting=nyt] didn't work
6. the citation must be different, as noticed above

Finally I have no clue how to do this:

Way 2

> (Ho et al., 2012; Ho et al., 2007; Ho, Sawade and Newcombe, 2012)
>
> HO, L.; DREYFUS, J.; BOYER, J.; LOWE, T.; BUSTAMANTE, H.; DUKER, P.;
>   MELI, T.; NEWCOMBE, G. Fate of cyanobacteria and their metabolites
>   during water treatment sludge management processes. Sci Total Environ,
>   v. 424, n. 1, p. 232-238, 2012.
>
> HO, L.; HOEFEL, D.; SAINT, C. P.; NEWCOMBE, G. Isolation and
>   identification of a novel microcystin-degrading bacterium from a
>   biological sand filter. Water Res, v. 41, n. 20, p. 4685-4695, 2007.
>
> HO, L.; SAWADE, E.; NEWCOMBE, G. Biological treatment options for
>   cyanobacteria metabolite removal: A review. Water Res, v. 46, n. 5, p.
>   1536-1548, 2012.

Comment: Please try to ask only one question per ... question. This makes it easier for the people that want to help you as well as for future visitors with similar problems. Many of the changes you want have been covered elsewhere on this site.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for the references (way 1). For citations, I used the style `authoryear-comp`  which is not quite what you want, but is closer than what you have now.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=authoryear,
giveninits=true,
maxcitenames=2,
uniquelist=false,
sortcites,
maxbibnames=99,
sorting=ynt,
url=false,
eprint=false,
isbn =false
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\addbibresource{Example.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\DeclareSourcemap{% requires biber
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=note, null]
    }
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield[parens]{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%For italic et al. %%%
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}
%%%

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\begin{document}
\parencite{Ho2012,Ho2012a,Ho2007}
\newrefcontext{sorting=nyt}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]